# Custom Validation in PHP Codeigniter - one of two fields required

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter

My form has a cellphone and a phone field. I want the user to fill either one of the fields, or both, but not neither.

I've seen ways to do it in other languages, but could I have some advice on how to do it with Codeigniter?

Comment: use callback to compare phone with cellphone

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Just do a JS validation on client-side, and PHP validation on server-side (or use CI's form helper)... Anyway, PHP should look something like this:

```
if ($_POST['cellphone'] == '' OR $_POST['phone' == '') {
// do stuff like make an notification, alert, etc... and take users back to the form
}
```

Comment: I have created an array of all validation in the config folder. so what should i do for this type of validation.  @Shomz

Comment: we need a rule not core php

Comment: @Darshanambaliya you can ask another question.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it as:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Your validation message.', 'callback__phone_check');
```

And make a function:

```
function _phone_check() {
   //check for phone and cellphone field.
  //make sure one field is not empty and return accordingly
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Where should I do this ? In view , controller?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com that should be in your controller..! Read more here:: https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to throw some quick code snippets your way. I wanted to accomplish this and this question was one of the first entries in google when I did my search. I took inspiration from the other answers and here's what I did which worked for me (YMMV):

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('contactVerify', 'Either Phone or Email is required');
...
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'trim|callback_contactVerify[email]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|callback_contactVerify[phone]|valid_email|xss_clean');
...
public function contactVerify($contact, $otherField) {
  return ($contact != '' || $this->input->post($otherField) != '');
}
```

Since this is a very simple validation function, I pre-set the error message so I don't have to set it inside validation function. I pass in the other field I want to check as the second argument via the square brackets.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this works anymore. I think if "required" is not present in the rules, no other rules are checked (for efficiency, I presume).