# CodeIgniter Form Validation using Logical Operator

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I use a logical operator in codeigniter form validation rules

I have this code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name', 'First name',  'trim|required');
```

which checks only one field. 
I have two fields: 1- company_name  2- username

what I want to do is something like this return true if either field if filled.

`set_rules('company_name', 'Company Name' || 'username', 'User Name', 'trim|required');` (this will not work )

how do I achieve this using codeigniter form validation with || Or Logical Operator

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116630/custom-validation-in-php-codeigniter-one-of-two-fields-required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116630/custom-validation-in-php-codeigniter-one-of-two-fields-required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use callback in rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name', 'First name',  'trim|required|callback_functionName');

function functionName(){
//do something and check anything here. return true this in any condition.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name', 'First name',  'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name',  'trim|required');
```

You can use like this

Comment: this will require both field to be filled . what i'm looking for is a way to return TRUE if either field is filled . not both . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set condition with:

```
if (!empty($this->input->post('company_name'))) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name', 'Company name',  'trim|required');
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User name',  'trim|required');
}
```